# creating own certificate for signing the assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, assembly-signing, strongname

I have created an assembly and signed it with strong name.

I need to create my own certificate to sign my assembly and I need to display the certificate and the signature.

Please give me some information about this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Makecert tool is used for that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: from that   i  can create the own certificate, but  how   how  can i sign my assembly  with that  certifecate